# When printing HTML, how can I determine how much space is left before the end of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, princexml

I'm printing HTML as PDF using PrinceXML.

I often print a series of images, some large and some small.

When I do this, I'd like to start with the largest image that will fit in the remaining space on the page.

How can I determine how much space is left before the end of the page?

Ideally using [CSS supported by PrinceXM](http://www.princexml.com/doc/selectors/)L, though I understand JavaScript may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

How about you obtain the height of the document and substract all other elements height above it.

pseudo format :
`total html document height` -(`your pdf/html height` + `header height`+`other element with height above page`)

Comment: would require me to know what other elements are on this page (not just in the doc)